# How do I change the fill color of a rectangle in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I thought this would be pretty straightforward, but I've been searching for a way to do this and can only find ways to do it with a movie clip.

I have a normal rectangle shape in Flash. I'd like to change the fill color of it using code, so I can use flashvars and be able to change the color of the shape with a few HTML adjustments.

Is this even possible?

If so, can someone please just post an example of how to do it.

All I need to know is how to change the fill color of the shape. I've got the flashvars sorted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`ColorTransform`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html).

```
var trans:ColorTransform = square.transform.colorTransform;
trans.color = uint(0xFF0000);

square.transform.colorTransform = trans;
```

Comment: Okay, but `square` looks like an instance name?

Comment: @Nav Well it's a property of type `DisplayObject` or anything that inherits it.

Comment: Right okay. I try using a variable with that, and I get this error: "1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type uint." any ideas?

Comment: There's nothing in my code that would cause that unless you've tried to wrap 0xFF0000 in quotes ("0xFF0000").

Comment: Are you trying to set the color from a flashvar?  When you retrieve a flashvar it will be a string, you have to convert it to a uint first.

Comment: I think your code was correct, but @Nav mentioned setting the color from a flashvar in the question, and if your code was changed to attempt to set it directly from a flashvar, that's exactly the error I'd expect.